# Problem about maximize profit

Tags: systems-of-equations

A company has 20 pair of shoes and 60 shirts to sell together in two different ways:

- A: one pair of shoes and one shirt for \$20
- B: one pair of shoes and five shirts for \$80

I have to find out how many types of A and B I have to sell to maximize the profit.

I tried to find the solution of the system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l} x+y=20 \\ x+4y=80 \end{array}\right.$$
but it doesn't work.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Your description says 5 shirts, but you put 4 in the equation. So I will assume 4 was meant. Solve the first equation for $y = 20 - x$. Now substitute that into the second equation to get $x + 4(20 - x) = 80$. Solve for x to get $x = 0$. Plug this into the previous equation to get $y = 20$. So those two lines intersect at (0, 20). Ie, you get \$0 per pair of shoes and \$20 per shirt. More information would be needed to determine max profit - unless I’m forgetting something. For example: is there any equation that models demand? Or a limitation on stock? Etc.

Comment: Woops missed the stock above. So if we go with 4 above then the maximum profit is achieved by selling as many shirts as possible. So any combination of sales that uses all of your shirts will maximize profit - like selling 15 x (1 shoe and 4 shirts).

Comment: Now, most likely 5 was correct rather than 4 (else the problem is too trivial). Performing the same calculations we get that x = 5 and y = 15. 

Selling 1 pair of shoes + 1 shirt x 4 = \$80, which is the same profit as selling 1 pair of shoes + 5 shirts. However, you’ve sold 4 pair of shoes and 4 shirts in the prior case while selling 1 pair of shoes and 5 shirts in the later. Since the profit of selling 3 shoes is identical to selling one shirt, there is no advantage in one or the other except in terms of stock - allowing for more or less sales. 

To maximize profits, maximize # of sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $x_1$ and $x_2$ as the number type $A$ and $B$ deals, respectively, then the problem can be formulated as the following LP:
\begin{align} \text{maximize} &\quad 20x_1 + 80x_2,\\ 
\text{subject to} &\quad x_1+x_2 \leq 20,\\                   &\quad x_1 + 5x_2 \leq 60,\\ 
&\quad x_1,x_2\geq 0. 
\end{align}

Converting this to standard form:
\begin{align} \text{minimize} &\quad -20x_1 - 80x_2,\\ 
\text{subject to} &\quad x_1+x_2 +x_3 = 20,\\                   &\quad x_1 + 5x_2 +x_4= 60,\\ 
&\quad x_1,x_2,x_3, x_4\geq 0,
\end{align}
then we can solve this using the simplex algorithm.

First, form the tableau:
$$
T = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 20\\
1 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 60\\
-20 & -80 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then apply pivoting (the pivots are indicated by squares):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 20\\
1 & \fbox{5} & 0 & 1 & 60\\
-20 & -80 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 20\\
1/5 & 1 & 0 & 1/5 & 12\\
-20 & -80 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \to
\begin{pmatrix}
\fbox{4/5} & 0 & 1 & -1/5 & 8\\
1/5 & 1 & 0 & 1/5 & 12\\
-4 & 0 & 0 & 16 & 960
\end{pmatrix} \to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 5/4 & -1/4 & 10\\
1/5 & 1 & 0 & 1/5 & 12\\
-4 & 0 & 0 & 16 & 960
\end{pmatrix} \to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 5/4 & -1/4 & 10\\
0 & 1 & -1/4 & 1/4 & 10\\
0 & 0 & 5 & 15 & 1000
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so the number of type $A$ and $B$ deals that maximize profit is $x_1=x_2=10$, respectively, with a profit of $1000$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the number of bundles A sold and $y$ be the number of bundles B sold.
You want to maximize the function $f(x,y)=20x+80y$ subject to some constraints on the available stock. Obviously, $x,y\geq0$. The number of shirts sold is $x+5y$. Since there are 60 shirts available, we have $x+5y\leq 60$. Similarly, $x+y\leq20$. If you plot these constraints, you'll see the region enclosed is closed and bounded. Since the gradient of $f$ is constant and non-zero, the global maximum will be on the boundary of the region (for example $x+y=20$ subject to the other constraints which imply $x\geq 10$). By direct computation, you can find that the max occurs at $x=y=10$ for a profit of $1000.