# Trouble with Implementing Dual Simplex Algorithm

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

For a homework problem I am asked to implement the dual simplex algorithm on the following linear program:

$$ \min -25x_1 -30x_2 \\
\\
s.t. 5x_1 +4x_2 \leq 120 \\
\\
20x_1 +30x_2 \leq 690 \\
\\
x_i \geq 0$$

Now the issue that I am having is that once this problem is converted to standard form by adding the variables $x_3, x_4$, the initial solution using the third and fourth columns to obtain the basis matrix $I_2$ yields the "optimal" solution according to the algorithm since $B^{-1}b = I_2(120, 690)^T = (120, 690)^T \geq 0$.

I feel like there is something I am missing in the setup to this problem because clearly this is not a solution to the original LP, but according to the dual simplex algorithm I should terminate immediately.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The termination condition you're using is wrong. If you form the tableau, you have that the entries in the last row are negative. So you must pivot.

Comment: What kind of tableau are you considering? I've seen the represented multiple ways.

Comment: Here's how the initial tableau would look like:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 4&1&0&120\\
20 & 30 &0&1&690\\
-25 & -30 & 0 & 0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The last row, with the exception of the last element, must contain nonnegative numbers after pivoting.

Comment: So then how is this the dual simplex algorithm? All you did was write the tableau for the simplex algorithm.

Comment: You've asked me what kind of tableau I'm using, and here it is. I assumed that you already know how the algorithm works, and specifically what pivoting is. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4677140/443030) answer I use the algorithm to solve an LP.

Comment: So I understand the simplex algorithm, what I am not understanding is the DUAL simplex algorithm. In particular for this problem we did not even consider anything regarding solutions of the dual LP.

Comment: Then you would know that you'd be working with the **DUAL** of the primal problem, and performing the standard simplex algorithm as usual on the dual, see [this](https://www-personal.umich.edu/~murty/510/510slides7.pdf)